# Math.Ceiling() on expression when dividing and multiplying by same number

Tags: c#, multiplication, divide

I have a little trouble with *Math.Ceiling()* in *C#*.

I call it on the result of a division by a number followed by a multiplication by the same number, e.g. 20 000 / 184 * 184. I would expect that result to be 20 000 but it is 20 001. Are there any possible ways how to avoid this behavior when trying round up value?

Thank you in advance

Comment: 1. What is "dividing snd multiplying"? 2. What language are you using?

Comment: Ooops sorry I am using C#... Well this is just random situation where these variables get in this function...i could check and then set in this variable back original value but I wonder if there is any better solution

Comment: Weird. In C#, when you divide integers, you always get integers with any decimals removed. The result is likely to be smaller than 20000; it should be something like 19872. It's strange to get 20001. Perhaps you should post the lines of code that exhibit the problem.

Comment: I think this code exhibits the problem: 
    `decimal twentyThousand = 20000;
    decimal oneEightyFour = 184;
    decimal result = twentyThousand / oneEightyFour * oneEightyFour;
    decimal newResult = Math.Ceiling(result);`

Answer (score 2):

When running the code you supplied we have the following

`twentyThousand/oneEightyFour * oneEightyFour`

The answer is `20000.000000000000000000000001`

Hence when you do the ceiling we have `20001`.

By the following article I think the result is due to in inaccuracy introduced when performing the division , this yields `108.69565217391304347826086957`  and as Jon stated

> As a very broad rule of thumb, if you end up seeing a very long string representation (ie most of the 28/29 digits are non-zero) then chances are you've got some inaccuracy along the way.

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx

Comment: This is exactly what happens ... so is here any good solution to this problem? Or should I just control in my code if these values are the same?

Comment: @Neox as it's the division causing the issue, doing the multiplication first and then the division.  Problem with this is that other values might cause the imprecision to occur at other places in the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

As light pointed out in the comments, you shouldn't be getting 20001 at all.

20000 / 184 would yield 108. Which then would give you 19872 when multiplied by 184.

Somewhere you are doing something other than what you posted. Where is Math.Ceiling() even called?

I will say, if the numbers are hard coded, you can put a decimal in the code and it will treat it as such. If you are using variables that represent numbers, be sure they are formatted as some floating point type (decimal,double,float) depending on the accuracy needed.

```
Console.WriteLine(20000 / 184 * 184);  // 19872
Console.WriteLine((20000.0 / 184.0 * 184.0));  // 20000
```

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any possible ways how to avoid this behavior when trying round up value?

In this particular case you can avoid the problem by multiplying first, *then* dividing:

```
result = (20000m * 184m) / 184m ;
```

Since the precision is lost in the division, multiplying first prevents that imprecision form getting exaggerated when you multiply.